# wp_editor not rendering the shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I have created an options page and have added wp-editor input in that. While rendering the output of that, it doesn't render the output of shortcodes added into it. It just renders shortcodes as text.

Could any one please suggest what I'm doing wrong?
Here is the code that I am using to get the output:

```
echo stripslashes( html_entity_decode(get_option('home_header_description')
```

I have already tried wrapping it in `do_shortcode()`. But my shortcode is like:

```
[show_more more=Read_more less=Read_less]
Lorem ipsum.........
[/show_more]
```

It is basically used for hiding text at the intial load and displays the text when 'read more' is clicked then again hides the text when 'Read less' is clicked.

When using `do_shortcode` what it outputs is it just hides the text and then doesn't shows the text when read more is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly add shortcode evaluation to a text field for it to work. By default it is only defined for `the_content` and `the_excerpt`. If you look at the [source of the first one](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) you see this line:

```
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
```

Among the [default filters](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/default-filters.php) is this one:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11 ); // AFTER wpautop()
```

So, for shortcodes to work in your case, you will have to modify the part where the text is echoed, to apply a filter first. Then you make `do_shortcode` one of the filters applied.